# Boto get s3 bucket location

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto

Is it possible to get bucket location in s3 using boto API ?

I'm talking about this function from AWS API - http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTBucketGETlocation.html

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can call the get_location() method:

```
conn = boto.connect_s3()
bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
bucket_location = bucket.get_location()
if bucket_location:
    conn = boto.s3.connect_to_region(bucket_location)
    bucket = conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)
```

http://boto.cloudhackers.com/en/latest/ref/s3.html#boto.s3.bucket.Bucket.get_location

Comment: For different buckets I have 2 different behaviors of this method:
1. it just returns empty string
2. it returns 403: boto.exception.S3ResponseError: S3ResponseError: 403 Forbidden

Comment: Make sure that your IAM user/role has permissions to call the GetBucketLocation API.

This is an API call on the Global S3 service, and not just a specific bucket;

`{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "s3:GetBucketLocation"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
    }
}
`

Comment: boto using signature type v2, by default, can it cause issue with 403 ? I added s3:GetBucketLocation but still receive 403.

Comment: You'll get an empty string (or LocationConstraint=None with boto3) for US Standard. You'll see 403 if you do not have permission to invoke s3:GetBucketLocation against a specific bucket (is it all buckets, or just some?)

Comment: What's the point of the code that follows `if bucket_location:` in line 4? If you can get the bucket in line 2 and the bucket's location in line 3, why would you call `conn.get_bucket(bucket_name)` again?

Answer (score 7):

For boto3, you can use the get_bucket_location method, which will return to you one of the following (as of November 2019):

'EU'|'eu-west-1'|'us-west-1'|'us-west-2'|'ap-south-1'|'ap-southeast-1'|'ap-southeast-2'|'ap-northeast-1'|'sa-east-1'|'cn-north-1'|'eu-central-1'

A sample method would be something like this:

```
def get_location(client, bucket_name):
    response = client.get_bucket_location(Bucket=bucket_name)
    return response['LocationConstraint']
```

See the [documentation for more info](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_bucket_location).

Comment: what it means if returns None?

Comment: A `None` return would indicate the the bucket does not exist or you do not have the permissions needed to query the bucket location. I would need to see more of the response to know for sure.

Comment: thanks @eatsfood, just found what i was looking for in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67370746/what-does-region-none-mean-when-creating-a-aws-s3-bucket/67370874?noredirect=1#comment119081279_67370874).